# Custom create action in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to add a custom create button in show page. I want only one create button in index page. I only want new button in show page alongside edit and delete.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :full_name, :email, :user_roles_id, :password, :password_confirmation

  action_item :create do
    link_to("New User", new_admin_user_path(@users), class: :button)
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :full_name
      row :email
      row :role do |user|
        auto_link user.user_role
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting two create buttons in index page for my model. It is also showing create new button in form as well. I want to remove create new button in form.

Is there any inherit solution like showing all actions in `show` page for all models from `active_admin` config file?

Comment: Isn't the form 'Create' button what's needed to submit the form?

Comment: In index page by default, there is a new button for create action, when I add new button for create action in show page, I get two buttons. Now I need only one create button in index page without removing the same in show page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to restrict your custom button to appear on `show` only with this:

```
action_item :create, only: :show do
```

And disable default `create` action with this:

```
actions :all, except: [:create]
```

Comment: Finally it worked with a bit change @VAD Thanks a lot